# Firebase User Properties - how to store a list value correctly?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

Can't store a list value. E.g. "autism, down syndrome, anxiety" or multiple interests "yoga, sports".

We tried storing each value separately, but then the values over-write each other. Storing "autism, down syndrome, anxiety, depression" won't work as there is a 38 symbol limit and nothing is stored.

This is really important for analytics. This way we can instantly measure in Firebase Analytics or DataStudio how for example "autism" users are different from "down syndrome" users etc. This is critical for our product and community insights.

Comment: Show us what you have tried in code.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in code. We are using firebase user properties. They can only store a 38 chars string.

We tried to store data values through a comma, but this data can't be used to create funnels, cause we can't get users which have one property from list.
for example, if user_property stored as "diagnose1, diagnose2" we can't grab this user when filtering by "diagnose1"

Comment: Have you tried to use an array?

Comment: what kind of array?  put [‘diagnose1’,‘diagnose2’,‘diagnose3’] instead of a string? Dart won’t even give me a chance to compile. cause method signature is (String name, String value)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, one stores user-related data as a distinct record in Realtime Database or Firestore using the user uid as key.

In your case, with Firestore (recommended) you may declare an array value and store your tags in it.

Comment: We know how to use Firestore. The problem is that we don't know how to store a list value in user property so it is presented correctly in Firebase Analytics Filters.